Tortoise SVN Error: Error while parsing config file
I created a windows 10 virtual machine with VMWare from my Mac, and after installing Tortoise SVN, any tortoise commands on the command line and any tortoise commands executed via context menu result in the following error:
svn: E200002: Error while parsing config file: C:\Users\jnick\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\servers:
svn: E200002: line 1: Section header expected

To debug I looked at the config, README, and servers files located in that servers directory and I found that they were all empty. I suppose that explains why no header was found since the config file is just empty.
I tried to repair the Tortoise SVN program with the installation file's repair option, but that didn't work either - same error. I also couldn't really find any more information about this particular issue online.
Has anyone experienced anything similar, if so, how did you resolve it? Alternatively, if you haven't experienced it, any insight into what the issue could be and a possible solution would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Installer repair usually does not affect the user data only the program data and AppData\Roaming is user data. You could have simply deleted that folder and reboot Window. TortoiseSVN would have recreated the folder and necessary files in it.

I just created a new virtual machine. This error was happening on a disk I had recently partitioned, so I just didn't do partitioning for the new VM. I don't know if this had anything to do with the error but now I'm not getting the error, so that's good enough for me.
